# Retrieve method that caused error using Rescue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rescue

Let's say you have the following example code block:

```
  def next_page(next_token)
    client.list_order_items_by_next_token(next_token)
  rescue => error
    binding.pry
  end
```

Without diving into the issue that this rescue is capturing all errors and how that is bad (this block has been modified) is there a way to determine the method `list_order_items_by_next_token` caused the issue? I know the stack trace is available but that does not feel right.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? It is not clear to me.

Comment: What do you think backtrace is for? It's exactly for requests like this.

Comment: I would like to know if there is a method that can be called that would return the name "client.list_order_items_by_next_token" :  I am setting up a retry section but I need to know what caused the error to pull a message from the locale file. @EddeAlmeida

Comment: @SergioTulentsev did that comment help?

Comment: @chrishough: it became a bit clearer what you're up to, but the answer is still the same. :)

Comment: dig into [`error.backtrace`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Exception.html#method-i-backtrace) ;)

Comment: Is that the only way @AndreyDeineko?  that would be rather slow right?

Comment: Let me address performance concerns in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use

```
error.backtrace
```

Don't worry about performance.

By the time you rescue the exception the cost of creating the backtrace has already occurred. The backtrace is created when the exception is raised. And it is expensive! Ruby has to create `O(N)` new strings whenever an exception is raised, where `N` is the depth of the stacktrace. Which can be 1000+ in a common Rails application. It gets even worse in a loop. And all these strings are usually never used and just clog up garbage collection. In our production system those backtrace strings are one of the major causes of performance degradation. But as I said, that cost occurs when the exception is raised, accessing the backtrace later is free of cost.